# Automatically import all incoming excel files from folder to any database

Tags: excel, database, automation, powerbi

I recieve x number of e-mails once every month with 3 kinds of excel sheets - 3 different types with different columns. They are all named by customer and which type it is. I have already set up a flow i Power Automate that automatically saves the excel attachment to place them in a specific folder (also in sharepoint). Now i want to transfer all the Excel data into a arbitrary database. Which one should i choose and how would i do it? The goal is to connect a Power BI report to the database.

I tried setting up a flow in data factory, but it only updates the specific excel file, but does not grab the new incoming files.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you want to do is to connect the folder instead of a specific file.

1. Connect to a Sharepoint folder:

[image]

2. Paste root URL:

[image]

!!!Don't forget to click on Transform Data

3. Filter the folder with your file:

[image]

Note: PowerQuery is case sensitive, so be sure to write exactly the same

4. Expand content column:

[image]

You'll need to chose your model file, but now every new file in this folder will be loaded in your report.

I hope this helps you

Comment: This could be helpful - thank you!

As mentioned i recieve 3 different types of excel sheets. Would the best solution be to place them in 3 different folders and then combine them?

Comment: Do They all have the same columns and contents? If yes, you can place them in the same folder. If not, I suggest placing them in different folders like: Folder 1: Files from XPTO 
Folder 2: Files from LorenIpspn 
And there you go